# Create multi views in a CChildFrame using CSplitterWnd

Tags: mfc

I am working with MFC MDI. I need to create views as follow. My ChildWnd is splitted in 2 parts. They are LeftView which is a CView and RightView which is a CScrollView. The LeftView is splitted in 2 parts, the TreeView and the the FormView. How can I do that?

```
_________________________________
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
|CTreeView  |                   |
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
|          |        CScrollView |
|___________|                   |
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
|CFormView  |                   |
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. I wrote the solution for anyone who has a similar problem.

1. In CChildFrame class, declare CSplitterWnd m_SplitterWnd;
2. In CChildFrame ::OnCreateClient put the following code:

   ```
   if(!m_SplitterWnd.CreateStatic(this, 1, 2))
   {
       TRACE("Failed to create splitter window");
       return FALSE;
   }
   pContext->m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CLeftView);
   m_SplitterWnd.CreateView(0, 0, pContext->m_pNewViewClass, CSize(0, 0), pContext);
   m_pLeftView=(CLeftView*)m_SplitterWnd.GetPane(0,0);
   CCreateContext context;
   context.m_pNewViewClass = pContext->m_pNewViewClass; //save original

   pContext->m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CRightView);
   m_SplitterWnd.CreateView(0, 1, pContext->m_pNewViewClass, CSize(0, 0), pContext);
   pContext->m_pNewViewClass = context.m_pNewViewClass; //return to original
   m_pRightView=(CRightView*)m_SplitterWnd.GetPane(0,1);

   int nWidth=rc.Width();
   m_SplitterWnd.SetColumnInfo(0, nWidth*0.25, 50);
   m_SplitterWnd.SetColumnInfo(1, nWidth*0.75, 50);
   ```

   CLeftView is an MFC CView derived class.
3. In CLeftView declare a member variable CSplitterWnd m_SplitterWnd;
4. In CLeftView::OnCreate, add the following code:

   ```
   CCreateContext *pContext = (CCreateContext*) lpCreateStruct->lpCreateParams;

   if(!m_SplitterWnd.CreateStatic(this, 2, 1, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST+8))
   {
       TRACE("Failed to create splitter window");
       return FALSE;
   }
   pContext->m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CPhongView);
   m_SplitterWnd.CreateView(0, 0, pContext->m_pNewViewClass, CSize(0, 0), pContext);
   m_pPhongView=(CPhongView*)m_SplitterWnd.GetPane(0, 0);
   CCreateContext context;
   context.m_pNewViewClass = pContext->m_pNewViewClass; //save original

   pContext->m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CPhongInfo);
   m_SplitterWnd.CreateView(1, 0, pContext->m_pNewViewClass, CSize(0, 0), pContext);
   pContext->m_pNewViewClass = context.m_pNewViewClass; //return to original
   m_pPhongInfo=(CPhongInfo*)m_SplitterWnd.GetPane(1, 0);
   ```

   CPhongInfo is a CFormView derived class, CPhong View is a CTreeView class.
5. In CLeftView::OnSize, put the following code

   ```
   m_SplitterWnd.MoveWindow(0, 0, cx, cy);
   int nRow2 = 227;
   int nRow1 = cy - 227;
   m_SplitterWnd.SetRowInfo(0, nRow1, 0);
   m_SplitterWnd.SetRowInfo(1, nRow2, 0);
   m_SplitterWnd.RecalcLayout();
   ```

Comment: This would be a good answer if you would tidy up your code tags.

Comment: You are casting a CREATESTRUCT to a CCreateContext. That's not a valid cast. It is only working by sheer luck that the CREATESTRUCT started with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6181/Simple-splitter-with-CWnd-derived-panes

[image]

> With this class you can make several panes arranged either horizontally or vertically.